# XPath Java library (evaluate functions also)

Tags: xslt, saxon, xpath-2.0

I am using Saxon-HE to parse XPath expression

For example: there is xpath expression:

```
string(xfi:identifier-scheme(xfi:identifier(/jenv-bw2-i:LegalEntityName)))
eq 'http://www.kvk.nl/kvk-id'
```

It has custom functions which can be found on http://www.xbrl.org/Specification/XF-PWD-2006-12-07.htm#_Toc152670686

I tried using Saxon-HE but I get error:

> net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Cannot find a 1-argument function named Q{http://www.xbrl.org/2005/function/instance}identifier()

How can I solve this ? Do I need to implement these functions myself or is Saxon-HE able to evaluate it but may be,  I am doing something wrong here ?
I also tried to use Jaxen for this

regards,

Venky

Comment: How would you want to provide the code for the custom functions? Saxon HE allows you to implement them in Java, see http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Processor.html#registerExtensionFunction-net.sf.saxon.s9api.ExtensionFunction- and http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Processor.html#registerExtensionFunction-net.sf.saxon.lib.ExtensionFunctionDefinition- and the documentation http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensibility/integratedfunctions/

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know why this was closed as off-topic as it seems a perfectly reasonable question to me - the question could be improved by providing more information, but it's perfectly understandable that you don't know what information is needed. So I'm nominating this for reopening.

Comment: Meanwhile, I'll try to answer briefly in a comment. Saxon doesn't know anything about functions defined in the XBRL specification. You will need to find a product that provides an implementation of these functions. Moreover, it will need to provide an implementation that works with Saxon. Certainly, you can implement the functions yourself, in which case Saxon documentation tells you how to do that. But that sounds a lot of work, and I would expect there are XBRL packages out there that do it for you. Search for XBRL software packages.

Comment: @MichaelKay The question had been closed before the OP's edit, when it still was mostly a resource request. In any case, it has just been reopened.

Comment: I don't think the OP realised it was a resource request, I think they hadn't understood the architecture and the relationship of the specs. But I might be wrong.

Comment: The question was closed because the answer is "You will need to find a product  that ... ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath specification defines a core set of functions which every implementation must provide (a library which grows from one XPath version to the next). It also allows additional functions to be provided by the implementation, or by the user, or by a third party (but in an implementation-defined way).

Functions like `xfi:identifier()` are defined in a different specification (XBRL) as extensions to the core XPath function library. Saxon doesn't implement functions defined in the XBRL specification "out of the box".

You will need to find a product that provides an implementation of these functions that works with Saxon.

Certainly, you can implement the functions yourself, in which case Saxon documentation tells you how to do that. But that sounds a lot of work, and there are probably XBRL packages out there that do it for you. Look for XBRL software packages such as https://www.reportingstandard.com/?lang=en

Comment: Thanks Michael. I should have realized that no library will provide custom implementation for XBRL functions. It looks like I have to implement them myself and Saxon certainly provides efficient way to do handle this.